# JQuery: Number of Array value exceed 100

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This question is a bit hard to explain so please tell me if this is not clear.

Firstly, i have a .map() function to handle some data, and since it is a for loop, it might generate a big amount of data.

And when i console.log() it , I realize that the Array has been slice in to [0-99],[100-200] like the image below.

[image]

And when i pass the array thing via node.js to the backend it turns out like below:
[image]

it passes all the number to backend as well and cause exception, how may i get rid of these numbers? It's working fine if the array didn't exceed 100

it not suppose to have something like "0":["1","2"]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fubT0.png)

Ok let's make everything clear. When the array "NOT" exceeding 100 it would pass normal array to the backend like below:

[image]

The problem is when it exceed 100 it will pass something like below instead and which our backed system cannot read it due to the array has some wield contains.

[image]

I am using .slice() to limit the max lenght of the array, so users need to upload data 100 per time but i want to see if there's anyway to fix it, may i could use .slice(), turn huge array into tiny pieces and .join() it back together?

**UPDATE:**

```
var array = $(".AdvKeyowrdAND").map(function() {
            return [$(this).html().replace(/\+/g,',').split(",")];
        }).get();
```

The above is the actualy Javascript code which handle all the elements

Comment: It hasn't been slices, it's just the way console outputs it.

Comment: but why does it pass all these number in node.js?

Comment: because js arrays are objects, and those numbers are just properties on that object (indexes of the array)

Comment: how may i get rid of those ? and pass something like Array[Array[1],Array[2]]?

Comment: Those are there shown because of the log function you are using, its just the way the array is printed using that particular method. You cannot remove indices from an array, that's one of its inherent parts.

Comment: it's browser way to print large array, only ask if you getting trouble with this?

Comment: i know its a broswer way to print out huge array, but for somehow it does affects my data which needs to $.post to the backend.

Comment: what exception occur? please state it as well

Comment: I have updated to question.

Comment: What is the actual exception?  As others have stated Javascript arrays are objects, and they have indexes as you are seeing. {0:[1,2],1:[1,2]} is the same as [[1,2],[1,2]]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your actual JavaScript code. JavaScript doesn't treat arrays of less than 100 items any differently than arrays of more than 100 items, and an array of 216 isn't remarkable, so I would guess the code you say you're using to `.slice()` and `.map()` the array is where the problem lies.

Comment: I have updated the .map() function